# asp.net user control binding

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

i created a user control with a custom property in the asp.net like the following. In the aspx page that uses this user control i have something like the following. The user control is in a FormView's EditItemTemplate

```
<uc1:MyControl ID="c1" runat="server" CountryCode='<%# this.DropDownCountry.SelectedValue %>' Value1='<%# Bind("Value1Col") %>' />
```

I am trying to use the `CountryCode` in the `Page_Load` method of the user control, but the value has not be populated.

My question is at which stage in the control's life cycle does the bounded value gets populated? I tried assigning value directly like the following and it does get its value at the `Page_Load` method.

```
<uc1:MyControl ID="c1" runat="server" CountryCode="CA" Value1='<%# Bind("Value1Col") %>' />
```

thanks,

the **uc1:MyControl** has the following property:

```
[Browsable(true)]
[Bindable(true, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
[DefaultValue(0)]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.Attribute)]
public string CountryCode
{
    get { return _countryCode; }
    set { _countryCode = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using databinding syntax you need to call DataBind method on your control - you can add this to the Page_Load method of the aspx page like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    c1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: thanks, i should have made the question more clear. The user control is actually in a FormView's EditItemTemplate. Not sure how I can DataBind the usercontrol in code-behind when it is inside the itemtemplate upon FormView's databinding event?

Comment: Where i have question is at which stage in the usercontrol's lifecycle  I can safely use the bounded value and change them in order for the Two-Way binding to work properly.